# How can I view updatedb database content, and then exclude certain files/paths?

Tags: debian-squeeze

The updatedb database on my debian (squeeze) server is quite slow.

- where is the database located
- how can I view its content and find out if there are some paths with useless stuff, that I could add to the prunepaths?
- how can I prune all paths that contain `*/.git/*`,  `*/.svn/*` and similar?
- why don't the files get excluded, I defined in `PRUNEPATHS` ?

my `/etc/updatedb.conf` looks like this:

```
...
# filesystems which are pruned from updatedb database
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf"
export PRUNEFS
# paths which are pruned from updatedb database
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /usr/tmp /var/tmp /afs /amd /alex /var/spool /sfs /media /var/backups/rsnapshot /var/mod_pagespeed/"
...
```

---

EDIT:

- The locate database is in `/var/cache/locate/locatedb`
- `locate /` will list all files and directories in the database (I looked through the results by exporting it in a file: `locate />/tmp/locatedb.txt`, download this txt-file and find large amount of useless stuff)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using the GNU findutils version of locate, which doesn't support the PRUNENAMES option.  Installing mlocate will provide these configuration options:

```
apt-get remove locate
mv /etc/updatedb.conf /etc/updatedb.conf-GNU.old
apt-get install mlocate
```

Now with the mlocate packge you can edit or create /etc/updatedb.conf and add these lines:

```
PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /var/cache /media /usr/tmp /var/tmp /sfs /afs /amd /alex /var/backups/rsnapshot /var/mod_pagespeed"
# the paths in `PRUNEPATHS` must be without trailing slashes
```

Then actualize the database with:

```
updatedb
```

You probably can remove the huge old locate database:

```
rm /var/cache/locate/locatedb
```

(The mlocate database is stored at `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`)

Check out https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mlocate/ for more information about the package.

(I spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to solve a similar issue!)

Comment: I had a problem after directly installing mlocate: http://pastebin.com/FLdZLXwJ - It seems the config file of mlocate doesn't understand all the options that locate does

Comment: Interesting.  When I had GNU findutils locate installed for some reason there was no man page for updatedb.conf so I don't know what exactly is supported with that version, but the man page for mlocate's updatedb.conf states "/etc/updatedb.conf  is  a  shell  script in some implementations", but apparently not in this particular implementation.  It looks like it only supports the PRUNEFS, PRUNENAMES, PRUNEPATHS, and PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS variables.

Answer (score 6):

Use `PRUNENAMES` as stated in `man updatedb.conf`

> A whitespace-separated list of directory names  (without  paths)
>   which  should  not  be  scanned  by updatedb(8).  By default, no
>   directory names are skipped.

The use of

`PRUNENAMES=".git .hg .svn"`

should do the trick (above line is the standard value on Fedora 18).

Comment: PRUNENAMES is not in my `/etc/updatedb.findutils.cron.local`

Comment: ... and neither in man updatedb. I use debian squeeze

Comment: @rubo77 Try the `updatedb.conf` man page, as was specified, then.

Comment: this doesentn seem to work. where do I have to add `prunenames`? I added `PRUNENAMES=".git .hg .svn"` and `export PRUNENAMES` in `/etc/updatedb.findutils.cron.local` and created a link to `/etc/updatedb.conf` too. then called `updatedb` but still all `.svn/*` files are found by `locate .svn`

Comment: Any ideas? It still seems, that PRUNENAMES and PRUNEPATHS is completely ignored on my debian squeeze server. locate still shows all files from `/var/backups/rsnapshot`

Answer (score 3):

`locate /` will list all files and directories in the database.

Answer (score 1):

> why don't the files get excluded, I defined in PRUNEPATHS

Although the OP's problem ended up being version/PRUNENAMES, as an alternative/addition to trolling through locate db output, running updatedb manually with the --debug-pruning flag prints the individual pruning decisions to stderr, and is really useful for tracking down pruning problems

For eg stick it into a file (as root in this case):

```
updatedb --debug-pruning > ~/updatedb_debug.log 2>&1 &
```

Sample output:

```
Matching bind_mount_paths:
...done
Checking whether filesystem `/boot' is excluded:
 `/', type `rootfs'
 `/proc', type `proc'
 => type matches, dir `/proc'
 `/run', type `tmpfs'
...
Checking whether filesystem `/mnt/windows' is excluded:
Checking whether filesystem `/proc' is excluded:
Checking whether filesystem `/run' is excluded:
...
Skipping `/dev/mqueue': in prunefs
Skipping `/dev/pts': in prunefs
```

etc

(Am using mlocate)