# where is the updatedb database located?

Tags: linux

I would like to remove with purge all entries of locate and its database.

I tried

```
apt-get purge locate
```

and

```
rm /etc/updatedb*
```

But is the database gone also?
Where is the updatedb database located on debian squeeze?

I would like to delete it manually too,
so I can cleanly reinstall it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On debian, the locate database is stored by default in

```
/var/cache/locate/locatedb
```

If you use `mlocate` as search indexer:

The mlocate database is stored at

```
/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

see: [How can I view updatedb database content, and then exclude certain files/paths?](https://serverfault.com/questions/454051/how-can-i-view-updatedb-database-content-and-then-exclude-certain-files-paths)

Comment: locate --statistics is the cmd line to tell where for any system

Answer (score 17):

No need to decompile the executable! Just kindly ask 'locate' :-)

For updatedb/locate (GNU findutils) version 4.6.0 try calling

```
locate --statistics
```

For me (on cygwin) this yields someting like

```
Database /var/locatedb is in the GNU LOCATE02 format.
Database was last modified at 2017:03:13 22:44:31.849172100 +0100
Locate database size: 6101081 bytes
All Filenames: 202075
File names have a cumulative length of 22094021 bytes.
Of those file names,

    2591 contain whitespace,
    0 contain newline characters,
    and 20 contain characters with the high bit set.
Compression ratio 72.39% (higher is better)
```

Answer (score 15):

`man updatedb`

search for 'FILES'

mine says:

```
FILES
       /etc/updatedb.conf
              A configuration file.  See updatedb.conf(5).

       /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
              The database updated by default.
```

Comment: That's mlocate, not locate. Though /var/lib/locate is not a bad guess for locate.

Comment: I'm trying to give both general advice and the results of following said advice on my system.

Comment: Oh, and it seems like mlocate is the standard locate on Debian.

Comment: mlocate is not installed, neither slocate

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to just strace the process, as it's going to lead you right there. This will be distribution agnostic and works if you don't have the man pages.

```
# strace updatedb 2>&1 |grep ^open|grep db

open("/etc/updatedb.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db", O_RDWR) = 3
open("/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.bUUaw4", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

[REDACTED in 2017]: See above answer: locate --statistics works.

If you have an /etc/updatedb.conf, you can look in there. I don't.
You can read the man page for locate, which says the default location is /var/cache/locate/locatedb. Mine isn't there.
You can use locate itself to search for files named "updatedb" or "locatedb".
I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: and if you search for `mlocate.db`?

Comment: @phil-goetz There's no need to decompile. You can get the exact location with a one-liner if you have **strace** installed: `$ sudo strace updatedb 2>&1 | grep -o "^open.*O_RDWR.*"`

Comment: @Cengiz: Clever! My update db is simply /var/locatedb .

Answer (score 0):

on mac --statistics is invalid

man locate

FILES
/var/db/locate.database                               locate database